# Presentation of long form in iOS

Tags: forms, mobile, ios, mobile-application

We're designing a very long form in an iOS app.

Our first conclusion is that the form must be split into multiple pages, since follow-up questions depend on previous answers (see here: [Long pages vs more pages](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28883/long-pages-vs-more-pages)).

Our second conclusion is that the next button must be both in the navbar and at the bottom of each page (see here: [iOS multi-step form and user input validation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38589/ios-multi-step-form-and-user-input-validation)).

So, our first question is: how many inputs should be presented on each page? E.g. some apps present only one input per view. And does this depend on categorisation of inputs? E.g. general personal information presented together.

Our second question is: what are the current different design paradigms for presenting the inputs, and which one is the most usable? E.g. table view in native calendar app, traditional inputs, etc.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How many inputs should be presented on each page?  And does this
>   depend on categorisation of inputs?

My thought is **the grouping of the inputs is more important than the number**.  For example, [the workflow for setting up an iOS device](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4053) is divided into screens for language, Wi-Fi, location services, etc.  The number of inputs for each grouping is less important than the scope of the question being asked.  For other apps, a sheet for the address information might have 5 or more input fields, while the creation of a username and password may only have 3.

> What are the current different design paradigms for presenting the
>   inputs, and which one is the most usable?

The [iOS Human Interface Guidelines lists all the native iOS device controls](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH15-SW1).  The guidelines recommend using the control that most closely matches the type of data and allows for gestures.  For example, it is considered more usable on an iOS device to use [a switch control](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISwitch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UISwitch) for yes/no questions as opposed to the radio buttons you would see on a desktop.  The recommendation is that **apps should focus on gestures and not clicks** to make it the most usable.

Comment: Great answers, and great examples/sources. Thanks Jonathan.

Answer (score 0):

The UX here depends on the type of input , user have to provide.

- Radio button [ 1 ]
- Check-box [ 1 ]
- Selection from a drop-down [ 1.5 ]
- Text inputs small ( 3 or less word in single field ) [ 2 ]
- Text inputs big ( 4 or more in single field ) [ 2.5 ]

---

Now check your form pages, and try to use the elements in such a way that the sum stays less than 6-8

> source: Case studies and experiences